# Semantic HTML best practice for a screen reader

Tags: html, css, accessibility, semantic-markup, screen-readers

Suppose I have a list of article previews on my homepage with the following design:

[image: Article design]

where there's an image to the left with all of the content to the right (region, date, title, abstract, and a Read More button that isn't in the image). How would you go about writing this semantically and accessible to screen readers?

Typically I would do something like this:

```
<article>
  <img class="image" src="path/to/image" alt="appropriate alt text">
  <div class="content">
    <div class=""info>
      <span class="region">Europe</span>
      <time class="date" pubdate>Date</time>
    </div>
    <h2 class="title">Article Title</h2>
    <p class="abstract">Abstract of article...</p>
    <a href="#">Read More</a>
  </div>
</article>
```

---

But, I feel like this could be more semantic and accessible for screen readers. One thought I had was doing something like this:

```
<article>
  <img class="image" src="path/to/image" alt="appropriate alt text">
  <div class="content">
    <h2 class="title">Article Title</h2>
    <div class=""info>
      <span class="region">Europe</span>
      <time class="date" pubdate>Date</time>
    </div>
    <p class="abstract">Abstract of article...</p>
    <a href="#">Read More</a>
  </div>
</article>
```

and since I have `.content` as a flex container, I can change the visual order of the children like so:

```
.content {
  display: flex;
}

.info {
  order: -1;
}
```

This way a screen reader will read the title of the article before reading the region and date. Does this make sense? I'm trying to become more familiar with semantic and accessibility best practices.

---

Similarly, would it make sense to change the DOM order of the image and the rest of the content. Like so:

```
<article>
  <div class="content">
    <h2 class="title">Article Title</h2>
    <div class=""info>
      <span class="region">Europe</span>
      <time class="date" pubdate>Date</time>
    </div>
    <p class="abstract">Abstract of article...</p>
    <a href="#">Read More</a>
  </div>
  <img class="image" src="path/to/image" alt="appropriate alt text">
</article>
```

And then change the visual order:

```
article {
  display: flex;
}

.image {
  order: -1;
}
```

Or would this cause too much confusion? My thought process is that I would like to deliver the most important information of the article to the screen reader first. Are there any reasons to not use this approach? Maybe users are accustomed to image first, content second?

---

Semantically speaking, is this how you would organize this code? Any improvements that could be made? Maybe wrapping the image in a `figure` tag?

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: You might want to take a look at [**ARIA**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/An_overview_of_accessible_web_applications_and_widgets).

Comment: Opening the `<article>` with an `<h2>` is spot-on (provided you have not skipped the `<h1>` on the page). I suggest you focus on the link text, since a page full of these will speak as "Read more" over and over in a screen reader. You can use ARIA to get around that, or off-screen text to include more text, or you can just adjust the copy.

Comment: @aardrian, in your other comment you mentioned not relying on Flexbox's `order` property--does it make sense in this case though?

Comment: It's not about whether it makes sense, it's about whether in this context re-ordering parts of the page for some users but not others is an issue. In this case, probably not much of an issue. However, you should still test it.

Answer (score 2):

### What's the best way to make an heading appear after a related content?

You can use the `aria-labelledby` attribute to indicate the label of the region

```
<article aria-labelledby="title1">
  <img class="image" src="path/to/image" alt="appropriate alt text">
  <div class="content">
    <div class="info">
      <span class="region">Europe</span>
      <time class="date" pubdate>Date</time>
    </div>
    <h2 class="title" id="title1">Article Title</h2>
    <p class="abstract">Abstract of article...</p>
    <a href="#">Read More</a>
  </div>
</article>
```

Note that, as the [article tag is not announced by NVDA](https://github.com/nvaccess/nvda/issues/3525), you may replace the `article` tag with `div[role=region]`

Answer (score 1):

I would definitely go with your latest suggestion (the image is last in the DOM and you change the order with FlexBox). This approach is exactly what I do in those situations.

And I don't think you should wrap the image in a figure tag. It would be more confusing.

Comment: So it wouldn't be confusing if the user's screen reader read through the title, region, date, abstract, and Read More button and THEN reached the image? My only hesitation is that they could navigate to the article itself via the Read More button before they even got to the image.

Comment: Because the image is just an add-on information regarding the article, I don't think that reaching it (still) at the end will matter. Most of the users I spoke to navigate with headers.
Also, I would probably add a title attribute to your anchor link Read More. The title could be: Read more about <title of the article>. 
See the H33 technique of W3C (https://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20-TECHS/H33.html)

Comment: Be aware that changing the order of content via CSS can cause unexpected results for some users: http://adrianroselli.com/2015/10/html-source-order-vs-css-display-order.html In general, I recommend against using `order`.

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't come across it already it might be worth visiting the "[Designing for Screen Reader Compatibility](http://webaim.org/techniques/screenreader/#linearization)" page of the [WebAIM](http://webaim.org/) website.  From that page...

> *Audio interfaces present content linearly to users, one item at a time. This contrasts with the way in which most people use visual interfaces. Sighted users can scan an entire screen almost instantaneously, comprehending the overall layout, the artistic style, and other macro-level aspects of the content. Screen reader users cannot comprehend these macro-level aspects as quickly.*

At the very least the WebAIM "[Introduction to Web Accessibility](http://webaim.org/intro/#implementing)" article should be an obligatory read for every self-respecting web-content creator.